# Find all books where availability is = 0 or unknown

Tags: sql, join, anti-join

I have a table `Books` which has many `properties`. Properties are stored as key and value.

So if Books are:

```
1  LOTR
2  Harry Potter 1
3  Harry Potter 2
```

And properties are

```
id  book_id  key        value
1   1        available  0
2   2        available  10
3   2        author     Rowling
4   3        author     Rowling
```

I'd like to get the results as:

```
1  LOTR
3  Harry Potter 2
```

since Book id 1 has 0 availability, and 2 has 10, and 3 does not have any availability info.

I know I can work with anti join, but I am not sure how to use it. I'm kind of new to anti joins.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you return `Harry Potter 1`?  Not understanding your expected results...

Comment: @sgeddes, seems 1 is used as a volume, not availability.

Comment: @sgeddes I used `Harry Potter 1` as the name of the first book. Also, what I'm after is, all books, where I know that they are all taken, or I am not sure of their availability. (This is a library management portal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding your question, but assuming you want to return all books that have no availability in the `properties` table, then here's one option using an `outer join`:

```
select b.*
from books b
   left join properties p on b.id = p.book_id and p.key = 'available' and p.value > 0
where p.id is null
```

Depending on your database, you may need to `cast` the `value` column in the `join`.

Comment: @cableload i am looking for books where availability is either 0 or "null"

Comment: @Amit, yes, the where part `p.id is null` will take care of the null part

Comment: @cableload -- this would do just that.  it will return null results as well as any that don't have value > 0, so 0 would get returned...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.book_id, a.key, a.value
FROM Books AS B INNER JOIN AnotherTable AS A B.book_id = a.book_id
WHERE a.key = 'available' and (a.value = 0 OR a.value is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT book_id, title
FROM Books as B
WHERE B.book_id NOT IN (
                SELECT P.book_id 
                FROM properties as P
                WHERE P.key = available AND P.value <> 0)
```

Note that `<>` means `NOT EQUAL`